# What can I use to typeset a part of MATLAB code (m file) in my document?

Tags: listings, matlab

I have a `.m` file and call `.m` file with `‎\lstinputlisting{****.m}`.  but I want LaTeX to show lines 13 to 25. How is it possible?

Comment: Shameless plug: you may be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).